# how to change the background color of a div dynamically according to the value getting from the model

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

i have one div that looks in green , i want to change the background color of a div according to the status value coming from the model,

```
<div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#008E00">

if @Model[0].status=="Normal" - Green 
if @Model[0].status=="LOW" -yellow 
if @Model[0].status=="HIGH" - Red
```

code

```
<div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#008E00">
                <h3 class="text-center">Xavier School, Nehru Rd</h3>
                <hr>
                DevEUI- @Model[0].deveui.ToUpper().Substring(11, 5) <span style="color:black"></span>
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <img src="~/images/manhole1.png" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-right paddingtop20">
                        <div class="huge"><h2>@Model[0].status</h2></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using Vanilla Javascript.
Here is an ES5 (compatible ES6) example of a method that lets you change the color of your div :

```js
var Model = [{status: 'Normal'}];

function colorMyDiv(){
    var color = 'black'; // default color
     
    switch (Model[0].status) {
       case 'Normal':
           color = 'green';
           break;
       case 'LOW':
           color = 'yellow';
           break;
       case 'HIGH':
           color = 'red';
           break;
    }
    var colorableDiv = document.getElementById('colorableDiv');
    if(colorableDiv)
         colorableDiv.style.backgroundColor = color;    
}

function test(){
  var states = ['Normal', 'LOW', 'HIGH'];
  var index = 0;
  var changeStateBtn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
  var stateLog = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
  
  changeStateBtn.onclick = function(event){
    index = (index +1)%3;
    Model[0].status = states[index];
    stateLog.innerHTML = states[index];   
  }
  colorMyDiv();
  setInterval( colorMyDiv, 1000); 
}

test();
```

```html
<button> Change state </button> 
<p>state : <span>Normal</span> </p>
<div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; margin-top: 20px" id="colorableDiv"></div>
```

Comment: tried like this , but not working
 <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:@Model[0].status=='LOW'? '#D8D8D8' : '#DDDDDD'" >

Comment: Sorry. I don't know why I assumed you used angular. I'll update my answer asap.

Comment: in source file , its showing something like this 
  <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:NORMAL=='LOW'? 'yellow' : 'green'" >

Comment: I updated the answer, here you have a complete demo that you can adapt to your case ! good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:@(Model[1].status == "LOW" ? "yellow" : "green")" >
                <h3 class="text-center">main road </h3>
                <hr>
                DevEUI- @Model[0].deveui.ToUpper().Substring(11, 5) <span style="color:black"></span>
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <img src="~/images/manhole1.png" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-right paddingtop20">
                        <div class="huge"><h2>@Model[0].status</h2></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```